# RabbitMQ - How i catch ForgivingExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rabbitmq

I'm trying to catch/cover all unexpected error such as error connection in rabbitmq. i've tried all what i think is related Exception (Exception, IOException, SocketException) even the general exception itself (all of this is not catching the error) so i can prefer other flow, maybe as example: doing log submit using 3rd party system, or notify admin via email while maintain code to reconnect for 3 more times instead showing this error message and stopping all execution.

Here's the uncatched error message :

```
16:27:51.476 [AMQP Connection 192.168.7.167:5672] ERROR com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured
java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:184)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:598)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here's my code :

```java
    package TestPackage;

    import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
    import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
    import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.SocketException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

    public class TestQueueSend {
        static ConnectionFactory rbmqFactory;
        static Connection rbmqConn;
        static Channel rbmqChannel;

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Properties rabbitMQConf = new Properties();
            try {
                rabbitMQConf.load(new FileInputStream("./config/rabbitmqconf.properties"));
            } catch (IOException errorLoadRabbitMQConfig) {
                errorLoadRabbitMQConfig.getStackTrace();
            }

            rbmqFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
            rbmqFactory.setUsername(rabbitMQConf.getProperty("rabbit_mq_username"));
            rbmqFactory.setPassword(rabbitMQConf.getProperty("rabbit_mq_password"));
            rbmqFactory.setVirtualHost(rabbitMQConf.getProperty("rabbit_mq_virtualHost"));
            rbmqFactory.setHost(rabbitMQConf.getProperty("rabbit_mq_host"));
            rbmqFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(rabbitMQConf.getProperty("rabbit_mq_port")));

            System.out.println("Running RabbitMQConnection!");

            try {
                System.out.println("Connection START : " + rabbitMQConf.getProperty("rabbit_mq_host"));
                rbmqConn = rbmqFactory.newConnection();

                System.out.println("Create Channel");
                rbmqChannel = rbmqConn.createChannel();

                String queueName = "queueTest";
                String queueContent = "Kasur ini rusak";

                System.out.println("Queue Declare");
                rbmqChannel.queueDeclare(queueName,false,false,false,null);
                rbmqChannel.basicPublish("",queueName,null,queueContent.getBytes());

                System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + queueContent + "'");

                rbmqChannel.close();
                rbmqConn.close();
            } catch(SocketException errorSocketCatch) {
                System.out.println("ERROR_SOCKET");
                System.out.println(errorSocketCatch.getMessage());
            } catch(IOException errorIOCatch) {
                System.out.println("ERROR_IO");
                System.out.println(errorIOCatch.getMessage());
            } catch (TimeoutException errorTimeoutCatch) {
                System.out.println("ERROR_TIMEOUT");
                System.out.println(errorTimeoutCatch.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception errorGeneric) {
                System.out.println("ERROR_GENERIC");
                System.out.println(errorGeneric.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

for other information, this is what i use :

```
Maven 3.3 
com rabbitmq amqp client 5.7.2 (5.7.1 not work too)
org slf4j slf4j api 1.7.26 
ch qos logback classic:1.2.3
```

for the ide i'm using :

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: Can you try debugging the code and report on what line the exception is thrown?

Comment: its thrown in **rbmqFactory = new ConnectionFactory();**

Comment: I don't get an exception at that line. I use 5.7.1 of the amqp client. org.slf4j slf4j-simple 1.7.26
Java: java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212-1.b04.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64
in Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0) on Win10

Comment: Since the only thing the exception reports is that there is an issue inside driver, try using the same driver version as [JWo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5852900/jwo). :)

Comment: i'm retrying with 5.7.1 and still got same issue. If you want reproduce this error, maybe you can run in windows and try to connect in another server (centos7 with rabbitmq 3.7.16), or use fake ip address as host

Comment: It seems this error message occured after program execution , because its still execute  syntax after catch block, need some workaround to hide this message.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because of incorrect usage of param: 
**virtual-host: /ABC** instead of **virtual-host: ABC**

Answer (score 1):

Because the exception occurs in another thread in third-party code, you cannot actually catch it without modifying that code. However, you can hide it, as you requested to do in a comment.

To hide this exception you could edit your logging configuration file (logback.xml for logback in your case) and set the log level for the `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler` to `OFF`. But I would **not** advise doing this in general as it could hide important diagnostic information. So a better solution might be one of the following:

1. Call `System.exit(0)` to exit the program before the exception happens
2. Alternatively, set the same log level dynamically to `OFF` at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because the rabbitmq user did not have permission to access the virtual host. After adding the permission the exception disappeared.